# Using a different foreign key with nested resources in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, nested-resources

When working with nested resources in Rails is it possible to use a value/field other than the primary key of the parent resource as the foreign key for the child resource objects?

e.g. if I have "books" that belong to "authors", I pass the "author"'s primary key to the book when it's created with `t.references :author, index: true` in app/db/migrate/[timestamp]_create_books.rb (right?).

Is it possible to pass the author's name, instead? (Assuming that the "authors" table has a "name" field...)

I ask because I have a preexisting table of books with various fields (author, title, subject, year, etc.) and it seems simpler to create an *authors* table with the unique authors from the *books* table and then join them where `authors.name=books.author` instead of having to figure out a way of getting the unique primary keys from *authors* to associate with the correct author in *books*. (But I am probably totally wrong about this.) (In any case, I am curious if it *can* be done and/or what the proper way of bringing in the preexisting database that lacks the author-book associations would be.)

(I apologize if my terminology is off.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your models:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, primary_key: "name", foreign_key: "author_name"
end
```

It should work. But this way breaks one of the Rails cornerstones: "Convention over configuration" and that's why you have chances to end up with total mess in your DB someday.

And what else attributes except 'name' `Author` model has? If there are few of them (or even only one - 'name') it will be better and easier to have only one model '`Book`' with the attribute 'author'.

Comment: That's what I thought. The Author model doesn't really need any attributes besides "name" (I was going to give it "country" as well but that's not really necessary).
I'm going to try to modify my database then, to import all of my authors in the proper format and then get the unique keys into preexisting "books" table somehow so that future entries can just follow the convention. Thanks.